# C# random dice generation -- how might I loop this until the user wishes to exit?

Tags: c#

What would be the simplest way to put this entire program in a loop allowing the user to keep typing in numbers until they type say, 'Exit'? Code is below, thanks for your advice.

I am a beginner but I have made a looping calculator with C# before, however it did not seem very elegant. I've tried a few loop ideas with breaks in this random dice program here but haven't gotten anything to work very well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RandomDice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Creates our object randomRoll as a member to the Random class.
            // By default Random objects use a parameter-less constructor,
            // hence the emply parentheses.
            // Classes are reference types, and stored on the heap.

            Random randomRoll = new Random ();

            // Simulate the rolls for the requested dice.

            Console.WriteLine ("Enter number of dice to roll: ");
            int diceCount = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

            // We now call the Next method, which is part of the Random class.
            // This method Next can be called on objects that are a member of the Random class,
            // which our object randomRoll is.
            // The +1 is because Next(6) returns 0 to 5.

            int total = 0;
            for (int index = 1; index <= diceCount; index++) {

                int roll = randomRoll.Next (6) + 1;
                total += roll;

                // If the loop is not on the last dice, print out a plus symbol after the roll value.
                // As an aside, if you wanted to start the loop at index = 0 as is conventional,
                // index would have to count up until it is simply < diceCount (not less than or equals),
                // and the printing plus symbols conditional below would have to be coded as
                // (index != diceCount -1) to adjust for the indexing since the loop 
                // would be starting at zero. But who rolls zero dice? So start the loop at 1.

                if (index != diceCount) {
                    Console.Write (roll + "+");
                } else {

                    // Write the last die roll.
                    Console.Write (roll);
                }
            }

            // Print the total sum of all the dice rolls.

            Console.WriteLine ("=" + total);
            Console.ReadKey ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just put the code in separate method and call it within the loop, at each  loop ask user to quit or continue. It is totally on one's opinion how to design app.

Comment: 1) put the dice roller in a separate method and call it until user types exit. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c-sharp%20how%20to%20add%20and%20call%20a%20method2) ask for input and test for "exit" within DO/WHILE loop https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c-sharp+do+while, and (worst case), add a label: and GOTO statement within the existing method https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c-sharp+goto . "I tried really hard, but please do my homework for me" doesn't cut it.

Comment: If you want to impress your prof, use Console.ReadKey(true) and test for ESC https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c-sharp+console.readkey

Comment: _"I've tried a few loop ideas with breaks"_ -- there are lots of ways to accomplish this. If you want your question to not be too broad, you need to show _what you've tried_, and explain specifically what you had trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

Use While Loop like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Creates our object randomRoll as a member to the Random class.
        // By default Random objects use a parameter-less constructor,
        // hence the emply parentheses.
        // Classes are reference types, and stored on the heap.
       Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to roll or enter Exit");
       string input = Console.ReadLine();
       while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
       {
        Random randomRoll = new Random ();

        // Simulate the rolls for the requested dice.

        int diceCount = Convert.ToInt32 (input);

        // We now call the Next method, which is part of the Random class.
        // This method Next can be called on objects that are a member of the Random class,
        // which our object randomRoll is.
        // The +1 is because Next(6) returns 0 to 5.

        int total = 0;
        for (int index = 1; index <= diceCount; index++) {

            int roll = randomRoll.Next (6) + 1;
            total += roll;

            // If the loop is not on the last dice, print out a plus symbol after the roll value.
            // As an aside, if you wanted to start the loop at index = 0 as is conventional,
            // index would have to count up until it is simply < diceCount (not less than or equals),
            // and the printing plus symbols conditional below would have to be coded as
            // (index != diceCount -1) to adjust for the indexing since the loop 
            // would be starting at zero. But who rolls zero dice? So start the loop at 1.

            if (index != diceCount) {
                Console.Write (roll + "+");
            } else {

                // Write the last die roll.
                Console.Write (roll);
            }
        }

        // Print the total sum of all the dice rolls.

        Console.WriteLine ("=" + total);
        //Get the input again
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to roll or enter Exit");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
  }
    }
```